# Where can I find out about sustainable electronics?

Tags: alternatives, appliance

Are there an online resources about brands or outlets? Are there certifications?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sustainable_electronics#cite_ref-4) refers to a 2014 Rank a Brand [report](https://www.fairphone.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/electronics-green-fair-ranking-report-2014.pdf) about the sustainability of global electronics brands in general.

I wonder if more granular information exists, especially about products in what Rank a Brand labels the "A" range?

The report mentions the [Fairphone](https://www.fairphone.com/). I wonder how to find out about similar products, such as toys, toasters, etc. that have recycled and reused components, and that can be repaired.

Comment: Note: the index they apply is quite a borad definition of 'sustainability'. Also the Fairphone was established in 2013, bit strange to talk about an electronics device sustainability in a report 1 year later. I mean: 2014 I owned a functioning Nokia phone which at that point was probably 10 years old, replaced battery just once. Afaic (ignoring possibly bad labour conditons) that's quite sustainable in the sense that longlasting = less labour, less materials to source and less waste. So even if another device outranks it, what does that mean should it last only a couple of years?

Answer (score 1):

Some resources that I know of:

- Current [recommendations from the EPA](https://www.epa.gov/greenerproducts/recommendations-specifications-standards-and-ecolabels-federal-purchasing) are to look for products that are [EPEAT](https://epeat.net/) registered.
- iFixit produces repairability scores for [smartphones](https://www.ifixit.com/smartphone-repairability), [laptops](https://www.ifixit.com/laptop-repairability), and [tablets](https://www.ifixit.com/tablet-repairability).
- In 2018, The Green Electronics Council released their [State of Sustainable IT procurement report](https://greenelectronicscouncil.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/GEC_State-of-Sustainable-IT-Procurement-Report2017.pdf).
- In 2017, Greenpeace produced a [Guide to Greener Electronics](https://www.greenpeace.org/usa/reports/greener-electronics-2017/) that ranked companies and products based on energy, resource consumption, and chemical production.